# ASP.NET: Changing Gridview Properties Dynamically in Devexpress

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress, dynamic, radiobuttonlist

I have a `Gridview` and `RadioButtonList` like this;

[image]

As you can see my `Gridview` can Enable for Editing, and some columns are `DropdownList` when editing. (also when it was bound)

[image]

I have 2 radiobutton in my `RadioButtonList`. **Görüntüleme** (It means `View`) and **Düzenleme** (It means `Edit`).

What I want is, If `Düzenleme` selected, normal Gridview can bind. (I can do that.) If `Görüntüleme` selected, Gridview can't has EnableEdit and I want all columns should be normal column. (`GridViewDataTextColumn`) So, people can only view the gridview.

The point is,

How can I change Gridview's `EnalbleEdit` and all column changed to `GridViewDataTextColumn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

### **For ASP.NET Gridview**

Just change

`GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = False`

### **For Devexpress ASPxGridview**

Just change

`(ASPxGridView.Columns["#"] as GridViewCommandColumn).EditButton.Visible = false`